# How would a Bayesian answer this question from Jeffrey Wooldridge

Tags: time-series, bayesian, econometrics, hierarchical-bayesian

Jeffrey Wooldridge, a famous econometrician, posed the following question to Bayesians on twitter:

> I think frequentists and Bayesians are not yet on the same page, and
> it has little to do with philosophy. It seems some Bayesians think a
> proper response to clustering standard errors is to specify an HLM.
> But in the linear case, HLM leads to GLS, not OLS.
>
> Moreover, a Bayesian would take the HLM structure seriously in all
> respects: variance and correlation structure and distribution. I'm
> happy to use an HLM to improve efficiency over pooled estimation, but
> I would cluster my standard errors, anyway. A Bayesian would not.
>
> There still seems to be a general confusion that fully specifying
> everything and using a GLS or joint MLE is a costless alternative to
> pooled methods that use few assumptions. And the Bayesian approach is
> particular unfair to pooled methods.
>
> One only needs to think of something like a simple time series
> regression with serial correlation. I think there are four common
> things one might do.
>
> 1. OLS with usual (nonrobust) SEs
> 2. OLS with Newey-West SEs
> 3. Prais-Winsten with usual SEs
> 4. P-W with N-W SEs
>
> In my view, choice (3) is almost as bad as (1). Choices (2) and (4)
> make sense, with (4) requiring strict exogeneity. But at least we're
> then comparing apples with apples.
>
> Again, what is the Bayesian version of (4) after priors and
> distributional assumptions are imposed?

What is the answer to Wooldridge's question?

**Glossary of acronyms:**

HLM = Hierarchical Linear Model, GLS = Generalized Least Squares, OLS = Ordinary Least Squares, SE = Standard Error, MLE = Maximum Likelihood Estimator.

Comment: This question is the cat's pajamas.

Comment: The Tweets start at https://twitter.com/jmwooldridge/status/1368557505018757131  I've corrected what I take as trivial typos in the original.

Comment: I have always understood GLS (more particularly IGLS) as an *estimator* for HMLs/MLMs (i.e. models). For example, the "standard" estimation approach in MLwiN is IGLS (or RIGLS which is a similar strategy to RMLE, as I understand it), and includes variance and covariance estimates. But one can also use MCMC estimation in MLwiN (including with a link to JAGs to get fully Bayesean with one's modeling of prior information). Am I misunderstanding something (i.e. GLS = estimator, and HLM = model specification/structure)?

Comment: Is this question, more generally, "How can a Bayesian 'fix up' her standard errors when she doesn't believe her model assumptions?"

Comment: Is there a particular reason for why he suggests model 4 (Prais-Winsten _and_ Newey-West) as sensible for simple time series data? It seems unnecessary to double-correct for serial correlation.